# How to prove number of permutations obtained by a deque is C(2(n-1),n-1)?

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

Given a sequence$\{1,2,\dots,n\}$,you can insert the elements one by one via both ends of the deque(double-ended queue).Then you can pop elements out of the two ends until the deque is empty.At last you can obtain a permutation.How to prove that the number of different permutations is ${2(n-1)\choose n-1}$?

It seems like the number is Type B Catalan number,and we already know that the number of permutations generated by a stack is Type A Catalan number.However I'm not sure if there is any relationship between them.

Comment: What does "Type B Catalan number" mean?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000984